# Jmeter - Break down huge JDBC query into multiple JDBC queries

Tags: jmeter

I want to perform jdbc query which returns 700K+ rows, then build my logic based on that, but when try to execute response time is too long, so i need to break down on multiple queries, each returning ex:1000 results.

My architecture is like:

[image]

1. 001_1 JDBC max_value - Defines the maximum value, of that 700K, which is increasing all the time.
2. 001_1 JDBC MAIN - This JDBC i want to break down into multiple JDBC requests.
3. InIt counter = `vars.put("counter","1");`
4. offset_value - counter element

[image]

5. While controller - `${__javaScript(parseInt(vars.get("counter"))<=700)}`

If i put hard-code value into the While controller, everything works fine, and my script is working; But when data-base increase the records size, then i need manually to amend the number of the while controller `700`, so can cover the next records.

Based on my understanding here i have 3 variables:

```
max_value = 714K
counter = 1
offset_value = 0
```

If i try: `${__javaScript(parseInt(vars.get("offset_value")<=parseInt(vars.get("max_value")))== true)}`

as a while controller statement, **offset_value** is still not evaluated, and while controller is not working properly.

How can i compare `offset_value` vs. `max_value`, so i can drive my While controller?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help @Dmitri T; However solution for me was:

```
1. Initialize the compare value as: JRS233 sample -> vars.put("offset_value","0");
2. ${__javaScript(parseInt(vars.get("offset_value"))<=parseInt(vars.get("max_value_1")),)}   -> inside while controller.
3. Counter: Track counter & Reset counter: must me checked both
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `parseInt(vars.get("offset_value"))` expression is being executed against not-initialised variable it will return [NaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN) so comparing it with a number doesn't make a lot of sense, you need to amend it to something like `parseInt(vars.get("offset_value")) || 0` so it would return zero on first iteration.

Also be aware that [starting from JMeter 3.1 you should be using](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) JSR223 Test  Elements for scripting and correspondingly [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) in the While Controller. More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)